# Using Tweepy, how to filter my search criteria by country and keyword/hashtag? (2023)

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python, twitter-api-v2

Code related to question:

```
import tweepy 
import configparser
import pandas as pd

api_key = ""
api_secret = ""
bearer_token = r""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""

# authentication 
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

# search tweets 
keywords = ''
limit = 500

tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q=keywords, count=100, 
tweet_mode='extended').items(limit)

# create Dataframe
columns = ['User', 'Tweet']
data = []
for tweet in tweets:
data.append([tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.full_text])

df = pd.Dataframe(data, columns=columns)

print(df)
```

---

Hi friends!

I am total beginner to coding and python (3.11), I am trying to use Tweepy for my Masters dissertation.

With tutorial help I have written this code to collect tweets based on a keyword (I know it only returns up to 200 tweets).

What would I need to add / alter this code in order to do the following:

1. Return 500 tweets
2. Collect tweets based on a keyword / multiple keywords / hashtag, and country from which the post was made / is set to in the user's profile
3. IF THIS IS POSSIBLE - once tweets are collected, is there a way I can review their status (modified/deleted) at a later date i.e. collect 500 tweets, one week later I need to check whether any of the tweets have been modified or deleted so I can make the appropriate changes to my data archive

Thanks so much for any help!

As shown in the image, I tried to return 200 tweets (although I have seen somewhere that you can collect more in one query?). I was denied access based on my subscription status (but I will be buying 1-month Basic access so should have the adequate permissions for what I am asking).

I was expecting to get back 200 tweets based on my keyword search criteria. But I need to refine my criteria to keyword(s) / hashtags and user location. I also need to be able to update the status of my downloaded data (all as detailed in the problem section).

I understand similar questions have been asked here before, but I think things have changed recently with the new access levels so I thought I would make a new post - also I need clarity for my specific problem as I am a total beginner :) thanks!